# how to save a detected face cropped from (object detection) to its particular created folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, save, object-detection

I'm creating a data collector program using object detection (cropped faces) but failed to save that in a particular created folder.

```
for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        sub_face = fl[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        FaceFileName = 'faces/'+ str(y) + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(FaceFileName, sub_face)#problem

        color = colors[i]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        cv2.putText(frame,label,(x, y + 30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, color, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FaceFileName = '/path_to_faces_folder/faces/'+ str(y) + ".jpg"
# save image
face_write = cv2.imwrite(FaceFileName,f1)
```

There may be a path problem. If it's, giving full path of `faces` folder may solve the problem.

**Edit:**

I am editing my answer with respect to your comment. I assume that you can get the label of your prediction for each image.

```
import os
predicted_class_label = "dog" # somehow you get it somewhere in your code
if os.path.isdir(predicted_class_label):
    FaceFileName = predicted_class_label +"/"+ str(y) + ".jpg"
    face_write = cv2.imwrite(FaceFileName,sub_face)
else:
    os.mkdir(predicted_class_label)
    FaceFileName = predicted_class_label +"/" + str(y) + ".jpg"
    face_write = cv2.imwrite(FaceFileName,sub_face)
```

Comment: it is working fine but I wanted to save the detected cropped image to the particular assigned folder name. e.g created folders cats, dogs , if the detected image is a dog then save that image to the dog folder otherwise save it in cat folder.